# hidden attribute for th in dojo datagrid is not working into firefox 7+

Tags: firefox, datagrid, attributes, dojo, hidden

hidden attribute to hide a column in dojo datagrid is not working into firefox 7.0.1, that particular column is hided permanently without depending on the value of hidden attribute.

I tried with setting different values to hidden :-

1) hidden="true"

2) hidden=true

But this attribute is working fine in old firefox version 3.6.15.

I am doing something like this :-

```
       <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="tableGrid" height="300px" >
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th field="first_column" width="auto" hidden="true">First Columnn</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
       </table>
```

So I was wondering if I am doing something wrong. Also please let me know if there is any other way also to hide the column.

Thanks
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like this defect in the dojo bug tracker: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11957

If you're not averse to patching your dojo source, there's a patch attached to the ticket that should resolve the issue.  It hasn't been applied to any Dojo version yet though.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Found more related ticket to this issue which has patch checkin :-
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11740